# Creating my own implementation of YAJSW Java Service Wrapper?

Tags: java, service, wrapper

After downloadig [Yet Another Java Service Wrapper](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) , in the wrapper.conf.default file I see the following comments:

```
# Java Main class.  
# YAJSW: default is "org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain" 
# DO NOT SET THIS PROPERTY UNLESS YOU HAVE YOUR OWN IMPLEMENTATION
# wrapper.java.mainclass=
```

Can anyone give me a link or an explanation of the basic idea on how to make my own implementation?  I suspect I need to extend some interface but I can't find info on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an abstract class to extend, `AbstractWrapperJVMMain`.

http://massapi.com/source/yajsw-beta-10.8/src/app/java/org/rzo/yajsw/app/WrapperJVMMain.java.html

http://massapi.com/source/yajsw-beta-10.8/src/app/java/org/rzo/yajsw/app/AbstractWrapperJVMMain.java.html

`WrapperJVMMain` is a pretty small class, so I suggest you copy-paste and have a play around with it

Comment: Thats what I was looking for.  Thanks!   It was really annoying to not be able to find this in their documentation (I didnt look at the Javadoc).

Comment: I always download the source & 'attach' it in my IDE. In this case I think the source is included in the zip :)

Comment: can you explain how to attach it to your IDE? do you mean compile YAJSW in the IDE yourself?

Comment: No need to compile it, just tell the IDE where the source is. For example, in Eclipse you can Ctrl-click on a call to a class/method, to view its source. When Eclipse doesn't know where the source is, it offers an 'Attach Source' button. You can then tell it where to find the source (in a zip, a folder, or a source-jar). So, next time you click on a class/method it'll load up the source.. Rinse and repeat for every dependency, and it'll get you looking at open-source libraries in a whole new light :)